# Why Flutter SDK constraints are not included in a pubspec file?

Tags: flutter, dart

We've seen Dart SDK constraints in a `pubspec.yaml` file

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'
```

But I never saw Flutter SDK constraints in it, although we can do this:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'
  flutter: ^2.1.0
```

But why do we never do this? IMO the reason could be that the Dart SDK version determines which Flutter version will be used and if that is true then why do we not get an error on using `flutter` constraints, it then should not be not there in the first place.

Comment: Because you download flutter sdk which includes dart as it's dependency. It we need to impose constraints on dart to work with our current flutter version

Comment: @osaxma Sorry that doesn't answer the question. I already took a look at it. Please read both the post carefully before marking it duplicate. Thanks